# How to install Pillow for Djangae

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

What is the way to include Pillow in a djangae project?
I placed PIL in the site-packages directory but I get the following error from Django:

> Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
>       HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install pillow".

EDIT:
Apologies for the typo. I kept writing 'Django' when I meant 'djangae'.
This is Django for Google App Engine.
Because there's no access to filesystem in GAE, for a djangae project, you typically have a site-packages in your project where you install the libraries you want to use. I copied PIL into this site-packages directory and even added it to INSTALLED_APPS but no luck.

Again, I meant djangae not Django.

In any case, this is the output of "pip freeze"

```
Django==1.7
Pillow==3.0.0
virtualenv==13.1.2
wheel==0.26.0
```

Pillow is installed.

EDIT:
The reason this wasn't working even after pip installing pillow was because I was running a different python version on my box :(.
pip was installed with the 'other' python.

Comment: so run pip install pillow

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I meant djangae, not Django.

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```
pip install pillow
```

and add it to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I edited the question. I meant djangae not Django. 
Please see my edit.